# AngularJs - Code accessing $scope variable before it is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope, http-get

I have a controller (MyCtrl). The first thing that is to be done is to make a `http.get` call and get the response and assign it to `$scope.input`. The rest of the controller depends on `$scope.input`. But the problem is the code in the controller tries to access `$scope.input` before the http call is finished.

How can I solve this?

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, factory) {
   factory.getInfo($routeParams.id) 
    .success(function(response) {
         //The factory code make the http.get call
           $scope.input = response;
    });

   //Rest of code accessing $scope.input before it is ready
});
```

P.S: I don't want to place the `rest of controller code` inside the `success` block

Thanks

Comment: Are you using angular-router or ui-router ?

Comment: I'm using routeProvider

Comment: Can't you wrap all your initialization logic inside a function and then call that function inside your success callback ?

Comment: @Arkantos I can do that. . The rest of the controller code has several functions and code blocks depending on `$scope.input`. So I'm afraid whether putting all that in one function would make sense in my case

Comment: As a matter of fact you're already placing all your logic inside your controller function :) With the above proposed change, you'll have nested function inside your controller. Now that you need to wait for some asynchronous call response, I think that's the easiest way to handle this. If you're at the luxury to change your router, `ui-router` has a `resolve` feature for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: @Arkantos Then I'll move all the rest of the code inside a function called `callback` and then call it from the success block. But still there are certain helper functions that don't rely on `$scope.input`. Those functions can be put outside of `callback()`. Is that okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99084/discussion-between-user7-and-arkantos).

Comment: Yup. Like I said only move the initialization logic to your `initialize()` function, any event handlers on scope, other utility functions can be left outside as they are now

Comment: I just found that ng-route also has a [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) feature. Posted my answer with both the approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option-1 : Using Some intialize function**

You can move your initialization logic to a function called `initialize()` and then call the function in the success callback of your AJAX call.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, factory) {
   factory.getInfo($routeParams.id) 
    .success(function(response) {
           initialize(response);
    });

    function initialize(){
       /* Move only the logic that depends on response from AJAX call in to 
          this  method.

          All utility functions, event handlers on scope are still outside
          this function
        */

         $scope.input = response;
    }

});
```

**Option-2 : Using resolve**

You can also use the `resolve` feature to load all the dependencies before you initialize your controller like below.

**In your router-config**

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/home/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl',
            resolve: {
                factory : 'factory',
                initData: function(factory,$route){
                   return factory.getInfo($route.current.params.id); 
                }
            }
        });
```

**In your controller**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, initData){
  $scope.input = initData;
  // rest of your logic
});
```

For more info on this controller-activate & route-resolve pattern, you can refer to [this](http://www.johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/) and [this](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/).

Hope this helps :)